# Dynamic Oracle Connection String

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that has a hard coded connection to an oracle database in VBA that I want to change to a dynamic connection. The code below shows the working connection string.

```
Private Function ConnectToSQLDB() As Boolean
Set m_oConnectionObject = New ADODB.Connection

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

With m_oConnectionObject

.ConnectionString = "Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
"Data Source=Test; " & _
"User Id=user12345;Password=password12345"    '* Create connecting string
.Open


End With

If m_oConnectionObject.State = 0 Then
ConnectToSQLDB = False
Else
ConnectToSQLDB = True
End If

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "ConnectToSQLDB()"
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Next
End Function
```

> DB name = Test Username = user12345 Password = password12345

I have tried setting the DB name, username and passwords to variable and then assigning the variables via text input boxes but this wasn't successful for me. Any one have any better ideas.

For further clarification I have tried the following code but it did not work for me;

```
Private Function ConnectToSQLDB() As Boolean
Set m_oConnectionObject = New ADODB.Connection
Dim YourPasswordVariable As String
Dim YourDBNameVariable As String
Dim YourUserIdVariable As String



On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
YourDBNameVariable = InputBox("Enter DB name")
YourUserIdVariable = InputBox("Enter DB username")
YourPasswordVariable = InputBox("Enter DB password")
With m_oConnectionObject

.ConnectionString = "Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & YourDBNameVariable & "; User Id=" & YourUserIdVariable & ";Password=" & YourPasswordVariable


End With

If m_oConnectionObject.State = 0 Then
    ConnectToSQLDB = False
Else
    ConnectToSQLDB = True
End If

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "ConnectToSQLDB()"
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: This should work `.ConnectionString = "Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & YourDBNameVariable & "; User Id=" & YourUserIdVariable & ";Password=" & YourPasswordVariable` 
Just remember to use string variables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but I have attempted this and I am getting the same issue as I was getting.

Comment: The code does not have the OPEN statement, right?

Comment: Just tested your code with SQL Server and works fine. ADD `.Open` after `.ConnectionString`. Is there any error message?